# Add PictureBox over Button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, picturebox, backcolor

As can be seen in the image, I am trying to create a minesweeper game, whereby a flag is displayed on a square (a button) when the user right-clicks a box. I set the flag PictureBox to a transparent background, and brought it to the front by using the BringToFront() method.

For some reason, the transparent background cuts through the original colour of the green squares, which is not what I intended. Is there any way I could use the transparent background (so as to get rid of the original white background of the image) without it cutting through the BackColour of the green square?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: What technology are you using?  Is it WinForms? WPF?  Are the green squares actually of type `Button` or are they something else?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Technology is WinForms. The green squares are of type button.

Comment: WinForms does not support true transparency.  Why don't you just set the `Image` property of the button to the image of the flag rather than using a picture box?

Comment: @Chris: What is "true transparency"?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway This is a brilliant idea, however I am not sure if it would be possible to resize the image to fit to scale with the button when using the 'Image' property. I could do so with picturebox by using 'SizeMode'.

Comment: `ImageList` can resize the image for you.